# Client socket waiting for server data with node.js

Tags: sockets, node.js

In node.js I'd like to create a client that:

- open a socket to "server1"
- through this socket: send info (array of bytes) to "server1" (this will activate a module on server side that will send data to client on irregular basis)
- read data sent by "server1"

Can I only use a socket that is created when my client startup and then wait for data from server1 or do I need to implement a server instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var net = require("net");

var client = net.createConnection(port, host);

client.on("connect", sendInfo);

client.on("data", readData);

client.on("end", cleanUp);
```

Just create a TCP connection to your server. Then just do stuff with it.

Comment: I have developed my client based on this but it seems the socket is closed after the first data sent by the server. In fact, I'd like to open a socket that will remain open so the server can send data through it whenever he needs to.

Comment: My mistake, the initial request I sent to the server contained wrong parameters. This is working fine, thanks a lot.